# Что делает метод subscribe в angular5

Tags: angular2, typescript, rxjs

Помогите все разобрать по полочкам что делает метод subscribe в angular5

Answer (score 2):

`subscribe` не имеет отношения к typescript'у как таковому, это название метода объекта типа `observable` библиотеки `RxJs`.
Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscription) или [применительно к angular'у](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library).
Если коротко то на вход даются 1-2-3 ссылки на анонимные функции-обработчика которые будут вызваны при обновлении данных observable, при возникновении ошибки и при завершении observable. `Observable` бывают разных типов с разным функционалом и поведением.

Answer (score 1):

Метод subscribe() подписывает на обновление запроса. Если говорить простыми словами, то после "get" Запроса на сервер, последний высылает нам стрим с асинхронными данными и чтобы их "поймать" и обработать мы используем метод subscribe().
Пример:

```
data: any;
getData() {
this.http.get(URL).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

Пример по другому:

```
data: any;
getData() {
this.http.get(URL).subscribe(function(data)
   { return this.data=data}
    );
}
```

В данном примере применяется стрелочная функция или лямбда-выражение(поправьте, если неправильно).